# Using parameters in the XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use parameters in the xpath expression but no luck.

```
field = //*[@id=%s]/optgroup[@label=%s]/*[contains(@title, %s)]"%(FIELDTYPE, label, fieldtype)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget about the quotes around the placeholders:

```
"//*[@id='%s']/optgroup[@label='%s']/[contains(@title, '%s')]" % (FIELDTYPE, label, fieldtype)
```

Also note that I've also added the `*` after the `//`.

Comment: You could also use the` `%r` placeholder to get the `repr()` of the string, which won't be exactly what you want in complex cases due to differences between Python and XPath syntax, but which might be good enough in most cases.

Comment: Btw, when do we need to use parameters in xpath ? (first time I am seeing parameters in xpath.)

Comment: Those parameters are not a part of XPath but rather being substituted by Python before the XPath expression is evaluated.